# Javascript Incompatibilities/Inconsistencies

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to do a presentation in a couple of weeks and was wondering: What are the top ten Javascript incompatibilities that you look out for when developing? What trips you up? I can start with one:

```
var somevar = {
 'internet': 'explorer',
 'hates': 'trailing',
 'commas': 'in',
 'json': 'code', // oh noes!
}
```

What are some other common gotchas that can't or aren't fixed by using a framework like jQuery or base?

Comment: What is the gotcha in the code above ?

Comment: The trailing comma (after 'code') can be there on some browsers, not on others.

Comment: That can trip up PHP developers who are learning JavaScript such as me, as I've grown used to PHP always accepting the last comma.

Comment: Note that this question relates somewhat to this question now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754689/any-references-for-differences-between-how-ff-and-ie-treat-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

var x = new Boolean(false); if (x) ... else...;

Is the 'if' or 'else' branch taken?

var x = "hi", y = new String("hi");

what is the typeof(x) and typeof(y) ?

Edit:..

parseInt("017") produces 15 (octal) instead of 17

The 'Error' object is a different signature from IE to Firefox.

When using objects as hashmap's, you need to use object.hasOwnProperty(key) to ensure that the property is not inherited through the prototype chain.

Comment: So where are the Javascript incompatibilities?

Comment: Whle not exclusively inconsistencies between browsers, this answer provides the most inconsistencies in the language.

Answer (score 7):

With HTML markup like

```
<div id="foo">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
</div>
```

If you obtain a reference to the outer div, it will have one child node in some browsers, and three child nodes in others, depending on how whitespace is treated. Some will have text nodes with the newline and whitespace as children of `div#foo` before and after the link element.

Comment: fortunately, this is something that libraries like prototype.js take care of.

Comment: I'm not sure that any library can handle all situations though as parsing of whitespace into the DOM isn't consistent across browsers, which I think was the point. (there is a loss of data which is impossible to replace) I'll try it later in some browsers to verify.

Comment: More of a DOM issue than a JS one though, JS is quite consistent about walking through the DOM

Answer (score 6):

Well, there's a problem with implied semicolons.

```
return {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}
```

Some people like opening brackets on its own line, like this:

```
return
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}
```

However, this last statement will return `undefined`, since the parser sees:

```
return;
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}
```

Comment: Thats a really good one.

Comment: But is it an incompatibility?

Comment: No, it's more of a gotcha. There aren't many incompatibilities in JS any more. The DOM is the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

Another one (don't think this comes up very often):

```
(typeof document.getElementById)
```

in IE: "object"

in Firefox: "function"

Answer (score 0):

There are almost no inconsistencies in JavaScript implementations across browsers. If there were, it would be a nightmare multiplied (by the multiple inconsistencies in DOM implementation). So "Top Ten Javascript Incompatibilities/Inconsistencies" can probably only be populated with "Bottom One" you spotted. Indeed there could be a pair more, but I would hardly expect them to be major or even worth attention.

Answer (score 0):

DOM API inconsitencies aside (which is what libraries solve), there aren't many.

But some JS engines have implemented [more features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.8), like [].map(), [].filter() etc, let statement or E4X. When I switch between Mozilla-targeted development (Firefox extensions, server-side with Jaxer) and general browser tageted development (websites) I need to remember what's available in every browser, and what isn't. So it's all about **what** is implemented, not **how** it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another one:

Regular expressions from Firefox to IE, there are lots of inconsistencies:

For the description:
[http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split](http://stevenlevithan.com/demo/split.cfm)

He publishes a fixed version of the RegEx object, and a testing page:
http://stevenlevithan.com/demo/split.cfm

Answer (score 0):

For the Date object:

```
alert( (new Date()).getYear();
```

Firefox returns 109

Internet Explorer returns 2009

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(document instanceof Document)
```

in Firefox: true!

in Internet Explorer: exception: Document is undefined

Answer (score 0):

An extension to altCognito's point.. Element isn't a defined base type either...

```
//uses jQuery
function getSomething(input) {
   if (typeof(input) == string)
       input = $(input)[0] || $('#'+input)[0] || null;

   if (input instanceof Element)
       input = $(input);

   if (input instanceOf jQuery) {
       ...do something...
   }
}
```

I had to replace the instanceOf Element with..

```
if (input && input.tagName)...
```

Would be nice if DOM elements were properly base classed in IE all around.