# any references for differences between how FF and IE treat javascript?

Tags: javascript, compatibility

Is there a list of differences between how FF and IE treat javascript?

for example, I remember array references was a little different between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Why yes I asked this question recently:

[Javascript Incompatibilities/Inconsistencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703993/javascript-incompatibilities-inconsistencies)

Note, that there was a clear consensus that MOST (but not all) of the significant differences were DOM related, not syntax related.

Answer (score 0):

IBM wrote a very good paper on differences throughout the browsers including javascript at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ie2mozgd/  Most differences are in the DOM and not necessarily in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [decent list](http://balanagaraj.wordpress.com/2008/05/07/javascript-differences-in-mozilla-firefox-and-internet-explorer/).